# Epic games launcher redownloading symlinked files

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, disk-space

Downloading a 150GB+ game on my SSD, I've symlinked some already downloaded files from the original D:\ directory to C:\ to free up space for new files yet to be downloaded,  although symlinking files works but Epic games launcher keeps downloading all the symlinked files again everytime I click pause and resume it  later.
Why does it does that and how to avoid this behavior?

PS: Can't download the game in one go due to limited bandwidth.

Comment: Assuming you did create the symlink using mlink did you use the `/D` parameter while doing so (is it actually a directory or a file) have you tried making it a hard link and did you check the [official help article on how to move installed games without redownloading](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-games-store-c5719341124379/launcher-support-c5719357217435/how-to-move-an-installed-game-from-the-epic-games-launcher-to-another-directory-on-your-computer-a5720215231515) instead of your hack?

Comment: Epic allows you to choose the download location of a game. Why don’t you just choose a different drive instead of using a symlink?

Comment: @Seth I've used mklink link target instead of /D because I intend to only link files as linking directory is not possible due to space constraints.

Comment: @Ramhound  not enough storage (115GB+) on any of partitions causing download to not begin, The caveat being, Epic games launcher has one mega folder where it downloads all files to unpack them later for installation. It appears, it not only overwrites existing symlinked files but get rid of them altogether and begins downloading new ones negating all the effort and causing the drive to run out of storage., seems like WinUnionFS might be the only possible solution but not sure if there's a release version.

Comment: Your explenation doesn't make any sense. Ripping a game apart across different drives by linking individual files is rarely supported and also a very bad idea for various reasons and also not really clear from your question. This is not an Epic Games issue in that case. The linked official help article also makes it seem like your statement is wrong. Using the available tools you are able to move stuff pretty freely but usually based on a directories. Using mklink and general ntfs mounts should be more than sufficient. You can use a usb key to move stuff temporarily off either HDD in case.

Comment: @Seth that help article is only for "already installed games" and moving directories is easy that way as there are usually multiple ones but here the situation is different, there's only ONE directory where all the install files will be and only individual file linking is possible which the EGS launcher doesn't recognize. 

My research so far hasn't yielded any solution, Epic Games launcher downloads all install files into a single folder so directory symlinking is out of bounds, unless EGS change their structure to divide install files into multiple folders in the future.

Comment: Is still don't see the problem. Move games that you have installed, free up 150+ gigs on one drive that way and symlink the download directory to that place. If you are struggling even downloading the game you will probably not have the space to install it. So grabbing a USB key/external hard drive or buying a new hard drive might be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

it may help
Open the Epic Games Launcher.

Go to Library.

Start downloading the game that is already on your hard drive.

Stop the download a few seconds after it starts.

Close the Epic Games Launcher; To do this, right-click on the icon on the taskbar in the lower right corner, and then click Close.

Copy the existing game files to the directory where you started downloading it (default: C:\Program Files[game name])
Note. For a previously installed game, be sure to delete the .egstore folder if it was created before copying the files to the new download folder.

Launch the Epic Games Launcher.

Start the game.

Note: with such a small download, you can run the game without having to download all of its files again.

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, I don't have "Existing game files", already performed this couple of years ago so I'm aware of how to trick the launcher into verifying existing game files. My question being how to segregate the "downloaded" files into multiple locations as I don't have enough space to download them all in one partition.